# Error in getting the tenant status

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

I have an instance of Stratos 1.5.1 running. After stratos sits over night without having been interacted with I get the following message on login to Identity Server

And I have added the autoReconnect to true both in the url call and in the property tag of user-mgt.xml

If anybody has an idea why the autoReconnect is not working that would be great. Thanks.

```
[2012-04-09 07:48:04,801] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.TenantManager} -  Error in getting the tenant status with tenant id: 2.
[2012-04-09 07:48:04,802] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.AuthnRequestProcessor} -  Error processing the authentication request
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 331,971,492 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 331,971,492 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager.isTenantActive(JDBCTenantManager.java:444)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.AuthnRequestProcessor.process(AuthnRequestProcessor.java:91)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.authenticate(SAMLSSOService.java:78)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:155)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:245)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed instructions at

http://www.lahiru.org/2010/07/keep-live-connection-in-wso2-products.html

to correct this problem.

What this says to do is keep the mysql connection available.  This required that i add these attributes

```
wait_timeout=259200

interactive_timeout=259200
```

and values to the /etc/my.conf file. I restarted and then waited 24 hours to verify and tried logging in again and this time it worked.